# What would be the output of a 555 multivibrator ic in bistable mode when both the trigger and the reset are set low simultaneously?

Tags: voltage, transistors, mosfet, digital-logic

Is such a state defined or should I expect random behavior ?

Comment: reset overides other inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [555 datasheet (TI)](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm555.pdf)

> During the timing cycle when the output is high, the further application of a trigger pulse will not effect the circuit so long as the trigger input is returned high at least 10 μs before the end of the timing interval. **However the circuit can be reset during this time by the application of a negative pulse to the reset terminal (pin 4)**. The output will then remain in the low state until a trigger pulse is again applied.

Ultimately this is not specific if Reset is active and Trigger is applied.

From [555 datasheet (Fairchild)](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/LM/LM555.pdf)

> When the **low signal input** is applied to the **reset terminal**, the **timer output remains low regardless of the threshold voltage or the trigger voltage**. Only when the high signal is applied to the reset terminal, the timer's output changes according to threshold voltage and trigger voltage.

[image: 555 Block diagram]

Every block diagram shows the 555 logic as a flip-flop.  Reset (active low) will always override trigger.